# Different results for the same query from yahoo.finance.quotes. (YQL)

Tags: android, rest, yahoo, yql, yahoo-finance

I'm using YQL  to retrieve some financial data. And I have noticed that lately I'm getting different results for the same query from yahoo.finance.quotes. For example:  [Query for oil price](https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22CLJ16.NYM%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=) done 5 times.

```
"LastTradeWithTime": "9:09pm - <b>38.29</b>",  
"LastTradeWithTime": "1:33am - <b>38.66</b>",  
"LastTradeWithTime": "2:32am - <b>38.72</b>",  
"LastTradeWithTime": "2:32am - <b>38.72</b>",  
"LastTradeWithTime": "9:09pm - <b>38.29</b>",
```

(But when you test [the same query from the YQL console](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20(%22CLJ16.NYM%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys) all results seems to be consistent.)

This behavior is really frustrating for the users (andorid app) - hit refresh button and you'll get very different results, hit it again and old results are back again.
There was a [similar report](http://www.yahooapis.com/forum/YQL/Inconsistent-results-from-Finance/1302578737000-2f9718d1-1ec3-3480-84b8-a7f2eb37b261) on yahooapis forum but it's very old. 
Does anyone have this issue and how to workaround it ?