# Incorrect close data from yahoo_finance in python

Tags: python, finance

I am using [yahoo_finance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance) in python to pull stock data and for some reason, the `get_prev_close()` method is not returning the same data with every call.

Here is a simple example:

```
from yahoo_finance import Share
from time import sleep

while True:
    stock = Share('XLV')
    prevClose = float(stock.get_prev_close())
    print prevClose

    sleep(1)
```

For some reason this will print two different numbers seemingly at random. So for today I am getting `69.3` and `69.71` printed out. But since this is yesterdays close data, there should only be a single value.

Is this is known bug and is there a way around this?

Comment: I don't know if this will work any better for you, but I found this package that seems to do a similar thing - https://github.com/cgoldberg/ystockquote/blob/master/ystockquote.py. I see that it has a get_previous_close function as well, but I haven't tested it. I'll give it a shot later today and let you know.

Comment: I just wanted to give a suggestion here. If you are using to pull the stock price repeatedly, you can observe that yahoo_finance is incorrect sometimes(I am not saying about being 15 mins slow). To pull the current stock price , google finance is much more preferred and to pull the historical data, yahoo_finance has better features. Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the realtime YQL data that the yahoo_finance package use are stale. 69.71 is the close on May 11. The correct value should be 69.3.

The easy solution is to either access the historical data table of the same package as in

```
>>> from yahoo_finance import Share
>>> stock = Share('XLV')
>>> data, = stock.get_historical('2016-05-12','2016-05-12')
>>> data['Close']
69.300003
```

Alternatively, grab the close data directly from the Yahoo/Finance website. (A lot faster and more flexible) When trying to replicate your situation, I don't get the flickering of values you report, but I do get a stale close (that of May 20th instead of May 23). Maybe the flickering you see is the result of the YQL sometimes going to a server with stale data, sometimes not. Here's code that gets the previous close from the historical data of yahoo_finance (a), from the realtime data of yahoo_finance (b), directly from the yahoo-finance real-time quotes (c) and directly from the yahoo-finance historical data (d).

```
import csv
import time
import datetime

import requests
import pytz

from yahoo_finance import Share

hist_url = 'http://real-chart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=XLV&a=4&b=23&c=2016&g=d&ignore.csv'
realtime_url = 'http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=XLV&f=p&e=.csv'

eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')

while True:
    stock = Share('XLV')
    a = stock.get_historical('2016-05-23','2016-05-23')[0]['Close']
    b = stock.get_prev_close()
    r = requests.get(hist_url)
    reader = csv.DictReader(r.iter_lines())
    c = float(next(reader)['Close'])
    d = float(requests.get(realtime_url).text)
    print datetime.datetime.now(eastern).time(), a, b, c, d
    time.sleep(120)
```

The close from stock.get_prev_close() in the 3rd column is consistently stale, while the other numbers are correct as per the following output:

```
09:24:51.582532 69.410004 69.69 69.410004 69.41
09:26:52.749902 69.410004 69.69 69.410004 69.41
09:28:54.589506 69.410004 69.69 69.410004 69.41
09:30:56.681914 69.410004 69.69 69.410004 69.41
09:32:58.255181 69.410004 69.69 69.410004 69.41
```

Comment: I was actually running this during open market hours. But that is a good catch that those who prices are two different days I will try using historical.

Comment: @TheNightman: Interesting. I'll try to replicate that tomorrow during trading hours. I just scanned the cross section of stocks and it turns out there are quite a few instances where 'previous close' as reported in the real-time data set does not overlap with that reported in the historical data. E.g. [the real time data](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=DNB) currently states the previous close of DNB as 119.76 while the [historical data](http://finance.yahoo.com/q/hp?s=DNB+Historical+Prices) gives the correct value of 120.43. I would definitely go with the historical data here.

Comment: @TheNightman. Indeed the problem does not really have to do with the change of values in the database after the new market opening. See the results in my edited answer

Comment: I agree, it is strange that this is occurring, but using the historical data works well. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there any change in URLs. Those URLs when put on browser address bar, not working

Answer (score 4):

This issue has nothing with [yahoo_finance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/yahoo-finance) python library. Inconsistent results from Yahoo Finance have been observed by many users. You can find complaints here [forums.developer.yahoo](https://forums.developer.yahoo.net/discussion/5555/inconsistent-results-from-finance) and here [different result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35938693/different-results-for-the-same-query-from-yahoo-finance-quotes-yql).
I've run couple of queries today and got different results as well.
Probably you'd better find another source for the finance data.

Comment: The page you linked to  was last edited over 3 years ago so may not be relevant now, what queries did you run today that failed?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I ran query `select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("XLV")` and result was inconsistent

Comment: Where are you running `select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("XLV")`? Is the data also incorrect when you visit the yahoo finance webpage or just through the api?